# Apple Aluminum Keyboard Function Key Broken in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard

Using the latest Apple Aluminum keyboard, the "fn" key seems to have stopped working. I'm not talking about being swapped with standard OSX, I mean the "fn" key doesn't register whatsoever, rendering, for example, F12 exactly the same as holding "fn" + F12.

The strange thing is that I swapped an older version of the exact same keyboard that was working fine... it appears that the hardware has changed here...

I've downloaded modprobe hid_apple to no success... I'm willing to jump through some hoops here... anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Does it work on a Mac or is it a pure Ubuntu issue?